# Second argument in sort function gives typescript error - Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

Second argument e.g **b** in sort function gives typescript error - Object is possibly 'undefined'. which I find it very weird as **a** is not, however they are the same type.

```
stories.value.sort((a, b) => a.story_score? - b.story_score?)
```

The whole context is here:

```
import { ref, Ref } from "vue"
import useApi from "./useApi";

export interface Story {
  by: string
  descendants?: number
  id: number
  kids?: number[]
  score?: number
  time: number
  title?: string
  type: string
  url?: string
}

export interface Author {
  created: number
  id: string,
  karma: number,
  submitted: number[]
}

export interface StoryWithAuthor {
  author_id: string
  author_karma_score: number
  story_title?: string
  story_url ?: string
  timestamp: number
  story_score ?: number
}

const error: Ref<string>= ref('')
const stories: Ref<StoryWithAuthor[]> = ref([])

const getStories = async () :Promise<void> => {
  error.value = ''
  stories.value = []
 
  try {
    const { response: stories, request } = useApi<number[]>(
      'topstories.json'
    );
    await request()

    if (stories.value) {
      const storyIds: number[] = stories.value.sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random()).slice(0, 10)
      await getStoryWithAuthor(storyIds)
    }
  } catch (err: unknown) {
    error.value = 'Error fetching stories'
  }
}

const getStoryWithAuthor = async(storyIds: number[]): Promise<void> => {
  error.value = ''
  stories.value = []
  try {
    for (const id of storyIds) {
      const { response: story, request } = useApi<Story>(
        `item/${id}.json`
      );
      await request()
      if (story.value) {
        const author = await getAuthor(story.value.by)
        if (author) {
          stories.value.push(
            {
              author_id: author.id,
              author_karma_score: author.karma,
              story_title: story.value.title,
              story_url: story.value.url,
              timestamp: story.value.time,
              story_score: story.value.score,
            }
          )
        }
        // Typescript complains about second argument
        stories.value.sort((a, b) => a.story_score? - b.story_score?)
      }
  
    }
  } catch (err: unknown) {
    error.value = 'Error fetching story'
  }
}

const getAuthor = async (userId: string):Promise<Author | undefined> => {
  error.value = ''
  try {

    const { response: author, request } = useApi<Author>(
        `user/${userId}.json`
      );
    await request()
    return author.value
  } catch (err: unknown) {
    error.value = 'Error fetching author'
  }
}

type useStories = { getStories: () => Promise<void>, getStoryWithAuthor: (storyIds: number[]) => Promise<void>, stories: Ref<StoryWithAuthor[]>, error: Ref<unknown> }

const useStories = () :useStories => ({
  getStories, getStoryWithAuthor, stories, error,
})


export default useStories
```

Comment: `a.story_score? - b.story_score?` is not valid syntax. I'm surprised you don't get an error about that.

Comment: Yep: [using proper syntax](https://tsplay.dev/mAK7Rw) means you get the correct error that `a.story_score` is possibly undefined. Right now it's just a conditional operator inside a conditional operator but no "else" part of it.

Comment: and can you tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: 1. Remove the `?` from the sorting function. 2. Decide what you want to do when the property is missing/undefined

Comment: can you give me a code example ?

Comment: `(a, b) => a.story_score? - b.story_score?` -> `(a, b) => a.story_score - b.story_score`

Comment: I meant more the handling of undefined where and how to do that?

Comment: try `(a, b) => (a.story_score || 0) - (b.story_score || 0)`